# Issue with Select after prepending option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selected, prepend

I am creating a `select` dropdown on the fly using PHP to get the data and build the options. Then I am using Ajax to fetch this (with the following lines) and prepend an additional option.

All of this works as intended, my only issue is that in the dropdown it always selects the second option which is the first one from my PHP / Ajax call but not the option that I am prepending before that.

I also tried changing `selected` to `selected='selected'` but that doesnt make a difference.

What am I doing wrong here or how this can be changed in jQuery / JS so that it selects the prepended option ?

**Note:** I am using this inside a Bootstrap 3 modal.

**My JS (shortened):**

```
var levelMain = $(this).closest('tr').find('.levelMain').text();
// ...
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php?node=fetchNav1',
    cache: false,
    error:function(err) {
        alert(err.statusText);
    },
    success:function(html) {
        $('#divLevelMain').html(html);
        $("#levelMain").prepend("<option value='' selected>" + levelMain + "</option>");
    }
});
```

**The Select is a standard HTML select that looks as follows:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="levelMain">
    <option value="some value">some text</option>
    // ...
</select>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$("#levelMain").val(levelMain)` after prepending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty easy to update the `selectedIndex` of the `<select>` element with the following:

```
success:function(html) {
    $('#divLevelMain').html(html);
    $("#levelMain").prepend("<option value=''>" + levelMain + "</option>");
    $("#levelMain")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this as well ! Just to check, does the last line do the same here what the other answer suggests ? It looks shorter this way.

Comment: @user2571510 yeah instead of messing around with the `selected` attributes, you can just change the `selectedIndex` for the whole thing and it should work the same.

Comment: Thanks for that - I decided to use this one as per the explanation provided. Works great !

Answer (score 2):

Are You making sure you unselect all the other Options in that Select tag?

```
$('#levelMain').children('option').removeAttr('selected');
$('$levelMain').prepend("<option...</option>");
```

or it may be that you should add the selected attribute after appending to make sure it is updated properly in DOM

```
var element = $("<option...</option>");
$('$levelMain').prepend(element);
$('#levelMain').children('option').removeAttr('selected');
element.attr('selected','selected');
```

cause the browser will default to the first one selected, then when you prepend it will stay selected thus the second one will be selected rather then the first one.

Comment: Thanks for this ! I decided to go with the other approach as per the explanation provided but this one works for me as well.